# Regular Expression, find between words

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that looks a little like

```
Name: xxx xxx
Company Name: xxx xxx xx
Company Type: xxxx
Tel: xxxx
Email: xxxxxxx
Postcode: xxxxxx
```

I am trying to pull out the xxx

I am using preg_match_all to do so but the regular expression I need is not something I can grasp :( I have been reading various tutorials around the web and now I understand it all less.

I presume I could do something like

find ^Name:(then any amount of words spaces etc till I get to) Company Name$ then ^Company Name:(then any amount of words spaces etc till I get to) Company Type$

if somebody could just start me off, maybe with a small explanation to help me understand things more, such as the term "matches" how do I define what is a match and what is ignored, as I just want the xxx parts in an array so if I did ^Name:[a-zA-Z0-9]$ would that all be a match or just the bit in [].

Regards.

Edit: Adding the php code I am using.

```
foreach( $value as $k => &$v ){
    if( $k == "history_date_created" ){
        $v = date( "D jS M Y @ H:i:s", strtotime($v) );
    }

    if( $k == "history_text" ){
        //Name: xxx xxxx Company Name: xxxx xxxx Company Type: xxxx xxxx Tel: xxxx xxxx Email: xxxx xxxx Postcode: xxxx xxxx To Email: xxxx xxxx Subscription: none
        $pattern = "/Name: (.*) Company Name: (.*) Company Type: (.*) Tel: (.*) Email: (.*)/U";
        preg_match_all( $pattern, $v, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
        print_r( $matches );
    }
}
```

basically I have pulled a row from a database, unfortunately "history_text" is a text field that in my opinion is stored wrong but I can do nothing to change this now so need to pull the different values with regex, the history_text field is created by a form so "Name:" "Company Name:" etc will always be the same, the values of each will not and are user in-putted so could be anything including blank.

Edit My answer:

No Reg Ex needed This is what I did in the end

```
foreach( $value as $k => &$v ){
    if( $k == "history_date_created" ){
        $v = date( "D jS M Y @ H:i:s", strtotime($v) );
    }

    if( $k == "history_text" ){
        $matches = explode("\n", $v);

        foreach( $matches as $match){
            $boom = explode( ":", $match );
            $value[$boom[0]] = $boom[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all("/Name: (.*) Company Name: (.*) Company Type: (.*) Tel: (.*) Email: (.*)/U", $x, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

A few notes about this:

- `.` captures any single character - except newlines (by default except
  newlines)
- `*` will extend it to capture multiple characters
- `()` will capture those in submatches You can also use other character classes if you want to
  limit it further.
- The `U` modifier (after the `//`) makes the matching non-greedy. This
  can be helpful to avoid .* matching parts of your "control text",
  e.g. when you have multiple matches on a single line.
- The parameter `PREG_SET_ORDER` usually makes it more convenient to iterate through the matches array which you can access e.g. by `$matches[4][2]` for the Company name of
  the 5th match instead of `$matches[2][4]` with the default pattern ordering.

EDIT: I assume that you know the actual "description terms" such as "Company Name" otherwise it will be impossible to generally distinguish between "(XXX XXX Company) Name:" and "(XXX XXX) Company Name:"

Also note that you will need only a `preg_match` to capture a single instance of such a 'line' while `preg_match_all` will be helpful to capture multiple 'lines'.

Comment: What you have done does make sense to me, though unfortunately it only returns empty an empty array. I will add a snippet of my php code above.

Comment: The pattern works for me using the string you supplied in the comments returning a correct array. (Although its not complete, I'll leave adding Postcode etc to you...) . However you cannot have line breaks in the XXX parts, if you need that you will have to add the `s` modifier.

Comment: ahh my mistake, think things have just become ultimately easier lol!
I was showing you the string from php's output without a nl2br so to me it seemed it was all on one line infact it is not each item is on its own line it seems

Comment: HA! no need to use pesky regex can just do $matches = explode("\n", $v); instead, but hasn't helped me understand regex any more. Your example has helped alot though and so I will accept the answer and bump it up :D

Answer (score 1):

It looks a little hard and complex to do this by only regex. But you can use regex for : (colon) symbols.

`/[^:]*/`

This will give you all strings before each colon symbol. Than you can cut last parts of all those strings. eg. `If subpos of "Company Name:" !== FALSE`, cut last part of that string. That gives you value of Name.

You can use same logic for other parts.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt really a good way to separate your data because there is no separator between xxxx and Company Name. if it was company_name instead, then this might not be such a problem.

look into a regex solution, or use the explode function (maybe twice) with ":" and with spaces " ".